# Wine issues with ubuntu 22.04 and multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, wine, 22.04, wayland

I use Wine mostly for running Mikrotik's Winbox.
I noticed some issues on Winbox's menus when the application is running on the secondary display.

If I open the winbox executable, drag to the secondary screen and click on the topmenu (File or Tools), the menu that should open just below "File" appears in a small size on the top left corner of my screen.

If I drag the application back to the first screen the issue will be gone and the menus will work just fine.

This problem wasn't happening on ubuntu 20.04.

```
Ubuntu 22.04
$ wine --version
wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had lots of issues with wine+winbox with setups counting 3-5 displays, both the rendering of windows and gui controls, the font issue and also the worst one the unhandled page fault which prevented me from launching winbox for few or 20+ times and after some tries of "launch, kill, repeat" it just starts to work until I close all the winbox windows. For the last one disconnecting of some or all displays for a moment helped. Please try the new wine v8 - it seems for me that winbox works now more stable - it launches every time.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1287977)

Comment: Sorry to hear that, still I think you should try the newer version of wine, I've been using it and most of the glitches are gone. Few that still are visible are minor and it seems like those are on the winbox side of things.